# SQL and PHP problems - only first category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I have a problem with calling some data from a database...

I have normal data that haves for each productonly 1 ID, but I have a categories table for products that have the same id twice and more, because a product can be in more categories. I have a query that calls data, but I don't know how to select only the first category in the categories table.

For example, the table:

```
product_id    |    category_id
2             |  31
2             |  12
2             |  31
3             |  14
3             |  38
4             |  10
```

This query I use to call the other data:

```
SELECT toc_products.products_id, 
       toc_products_description.products_name, 
       toc_products.manufacturers_id, 
       toc_products.products_price, 
       toc_products_description.products_url, 
       toc_manufacturers.manufacturers_id, 
       toc_manufacturers.manufacturers_name 
FROM   toc_products, 
       toc_products_description, 
       toc_manufacturers 
WHERE  toc_products.products_id = toc_products_description.products_id 
       AND toc_products.manufacturers_id = toc_manufacturers.manufacturers_id 
       AND toc_products_description.language_id = 14 
ORDER  BY toc_products.products_id
```

So i need all this to call in while, for now I have only this:

```
    while($red = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){
    if ($red['products_quantity'] = 0) {$red['products_quantity'] = 'Nicht lagernd';}
    else {$red['products_quantity'] = 'Lagernd';}

    echo $red['products_id']. ", ". $red['products_name']. ", ". $red['products_price']. ", ". $red['manufacturers_name']. ", ". $red['products_url'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Is there a way to call in the query only the first value with an ID, when the next have the same ID to skip it??

Please help, and sorry for my english... Thanks

Comment: there is nothing like category_id in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you have basically 3 options.

the first is to select the category id in your sql, and **order** by it. Actually your order by 1) product and 2) category. Then you can check in php if it has changed, like that.

```
$oldCategory = null;
while($red = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat))
{
    if ( $oldCategory != $red['category'] )
    {
    if ($red['products_quantity'] = 0) $red['products_quantity'] = 'Nicht lagernd';
    else $red['products_quantity'] = 'Lagernd';

    echo $red['products_id'], ", ", $red['products_name'], ", ", $red['products_price'], ", ", $red['manufacturers_name'], ", ", $red['products_url'];
    echo "<br />";
    }
    $oldCategory = $red['category'];
}
```

the second: you don't change your sql and can create a php function that retrieves the category from the database, for each product.

the third: you do it in pure sql. good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `GROUP BY category_id` to the bottom of your statement

```
SELECT toc_products.products_id, 
       toc_products_description.products_name, 
       toc_products.manufacturers_id, 
       toc_products.products_price, 
       toc_products_description.products_url, 
       toc_manufacturers.manufacturers_id, 
       toc_manufacturers.manufacturers_name 
FROM   toc_products, 
       toc_products_description, 
       toc_manufacturers 
WHERE  toc_products.products_id = toc_products_description.products_id 
       AND toc_products.manufacturers_id = toc_manufacturers.manufacturers_id 
       AND toc_products_description.language_id = 14 
ORDER  BY toc_products.products_id
GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: you can't group by a field without aggreagting the other return values (with max() or sum())